# How to Create a hierarchy with FOR XML on SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-xml-path

I Got the following 2 tables with data

```
declare @tab1 table(a int, name varchar(10), street varchar(20))
insert @tab1 values(1,'Bruce', 'my street')
insert @tab1 values(2,'Chuck', 'another street')

declare @tab2 table(a int, b varchar(10))
insert @tab2 values(1,'a')
insert @tab2 values(1,'b')
insert @tab2 values(2,'c')
insert @tab2 values(2,'e')
```

I'm try to create a XML document that should look like this

```
<Person>
    <PersonInfo>
        <Name>Bruce</Name>
        <Street>my street</Street>
    </PersonInfo>
    <PersonSkill>
        <Type>a</Type>
        <Type>b</Type>
    </PersonSkill>
</Person>
```

So far my SQL looks like this

```
SELECT name AS "PersonInfo/Name", 
street AS "PersonInfo/Street",
b AS "PersonSkill/Type"
FROM @tab1 t1 JOIN @tab2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
WHERE NAME = 'Bruce'
FOR XML PATH('Person')
```

And gives this result

```
<Person>
    <PersonInfo>
        <Name>Bruce</Name>
        <Street>my street</Street>
    </PersonInfo>
    <PersonSkill>
        <Type>a</Type>
    </PersonSkill>
</Person>
<Person>
    <PersonInfo>
        <Name>Bruce</Name>
        <Street>my street</Street>
    </PersonInfo>
    <PersonSkill>
        <Type>b</Type>
    </PersonSkill>
</Person>
```

How can I avoid getting 2 documents?

Comment: 2 docuemnts? or 2 record need of table2?

Comment: I need to have both rows from tab2 inserted into the document. <PersonSkill>
        <Type>a</Type> <----First row from tab2
        <Type>b</Type> <----Second row from tab2
    </PersonSkill>

Comment: its not possible as your data structure..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a correlated sub query in the column list against `@tab2`.

```
select T1.name as 'PersonInfo/Name',
       T1.street as 'PersonInfo/Street',
       (
       select T2.b as '*' 
       from @tab2 as T2
       where T2.a = T1.a
       for xml path('Type'), root('PersonSkill'), type
       ) 
from @tab1 as T1
where T1.name = 'Bruce'
for xml path('Person')
```